# Angular JS function use $scope or not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

According to the Angular docs:

> Scope is the glue between application controller and the view. During the template linking phase the directives set up $watch expressions on the scope. The $watch allows the directives to be notified of property changes, which allows the directive to render the updated value to the DOM.

Now my Question is : **if my function is not connected to the view, should we use $scope or not**?

Comment: I think you shouldn't. It will improve your app performance, because  function not connected to scope will not be checked in each digest cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean if you should do $scope.functionName = function(), even if the function isn't connected to the view.

No you shouldn't, why would you expose a function to the view, which isn't needed to the view? Also you get a better overview which functions is internally when only using function funcName().

Comment: correct, that is what I thought, but not using $scope, can make that function global. and it would be accessible from any where. right?

Comment: I dont think so. It is still in the context of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `$scope` to declare every function you are using, especially if it's not connected to the view.

However, there are some cases you need to use the `$scope` in a function not connected to view, for example if you want to emit/receive/broadcast a message on the scope tree or access something on a parent scope (although it's not necessarly a good practice).

Comment: If you want to emit/receive/brodcast you can use service and pass $scope as argument to some method from that service.